# How to Pass a JSON object as a parameter with an url?

Tags: javascript, url, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm using the below url to pass few parameters along with the url. But I want to pass an JSON object instead of params.

So any solution or suggestion from your end.

```
javascript:void window.open("http://173.229.213.72:9000/index.html#/myurl/seeallmyassets/**param_1/param_2**"%2C""%2C"toolbar=no%2Clocation=no%2Cdirectories=no%2Cstatus=no%2Cmenubar=no%2Cscrollbars=no%2Cresizable=1%2Ccopyhistory=no%2Cwidth=1050%2Cheight=750%2Ctop=42%2Cleft=195");
```

I am using angular js 1.5 also tell me the what I need to do in the state provider.

$stateProvider.state('myurl', { 
                 url: '/test/:param_1/:param_2/:param_3', 
         templateUrl: 'common/templates/myUrl.html', 
          controller: 'myCtrl' 
});

I want to pass request = {
                          param_1: abc,
                          param_2 :def,
                          param_1: ghi,
                          param_2 :jkl,
                          param_1: mno,
                          param_2 :pqr,
                          param_1: stv,
                          param_2 :uvw,
                          param_1: xyz,
                          param_2 :qwe
                           };
"http://173.229.213.72:9000/index.html#/myurl/seeallmyassets/:request"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it as a string, after encoding it:

```
var uri = "http://173.229.213.72:9000/index.html#/myurl?jsonObj={'property1':'val1', 'property2':54}";
var encodedUri = encodeURI(uri)
window.open(encodedUri );
```

Comment: So in state provider what I need to send $stateProvider.state('myurl', {
        url: '/test/:param_1/:param_2/:param_3',
        templateUrl: 'common/templates/myUrl.html',
        controller: 'myCtrl'
    });

Comment: Oh well... I posted my answer before you add 'I am using angular js 1.5', I can't answer on that, I don't know enough about angular

Comment: This can break if the one of the json key values has an `&` in it.  IE: `action=go&jsonObj={'key1': "this & that", "key2" : "hello world"}`  - if you pass this to another script you must first parse the parameters, and then reconvert the `jsonObj` parameter back into a real object - but the parsing part will split on all the `&` - which will also split the jsonObj into param1 and param2.  Its a tricky one I am dealing with right now....and using encodeURI() doesn't exactly help when using `new URL()` or `new URLSearchParams()`; to try and split the url string back into parameters.